# Why my Go Benchmark function can not stop?

Tags: go, benchmarking

**Why my Go Benchmark function can not stop ?** 
**What is the right way to limit benchmark times in Go?**

I want to limit benchmark run times, so i write code like this:

```golang
func BenchmarkSimple(b *testing.B) {
    b.N = 200
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if i%100 == 0 {
            fmt.Println("do something", i)
            continue
        }

        fmt.Println("do other thing", i)
    }
}
```

when i run command to benchmark it, it seem can not stop

```sh
 go test -bench BenchmarkSimple
```

go env like this:

```sh
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/sinksmell/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/sinksmell/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/sinksmell/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB="gopkg.mihoyo.com"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/sinksmell/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.google.cn"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/r9/6n1x2r_s5kq9xncqdt_dplk40000gp/T/go-build471996324=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

**Thanks for you read !**

Comment: `b.N` is filled / provided by the benchmarking framework. You're not supposed to change it!

Comment: The correct way is using [the `-benchtime` parameter to `go test`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test).

Answer (score 2):

As @icza pointed out in the comments, `testing.B.N` should only be read, not written by your code. The testing framework sets `N`, telling your code how many iterations to run. It measures the time it takes to run `N` iterations, then divides by `N` to get the time per iteration. The testing framework may call your benchmark function multiple times, varying `N` based on how long the function takes and how consistent the results are.

As @Adrian pointed out in the comments, you can control the time spent benchmarking with the `-benchtime` command line flag. It can be set to a duration (like `-benchtime=60x`) or a number of iterations (like `-benchtime=1000x`).